# 2 column with floating wrappers

Tags: html, css

I am trying to float a group of wrappers in 2 columns so that they will sit next to each other.  Problem is that when a wrapper is larger (or smaller) than the others, I would like the other column to re-balance to that the 2 columns are event.

Below is the code that I am using and an image of what I am trying to achieve.  Can anyone suggest anything that can help?

```
 <div id="mainCategoryWrapper">
    <div class="CategoryWrapper" id="Wrapper_1"></div>
    <div class="CategoryWrapper" id="Wrapper_2"></div>
    <div class="CategoryWrapper" id="Wrapper_3"></div>
    <div class="CategoryWrapper" id="Wrapper_4"></div>
    <div class="CategoryWrapper" id="Wrapper_5"></div>
    <div class="CategoryWrapper" id="Wrapper_6"></div>
    <div class="CategoryWrapper" id="Wrapper_7"></div>
    <div class="CategoryWrapper" id="Wrapper_8"></div>
    <div class="CategoryWrapper" id="Wrapper_9"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For this type of functionally you need http://masonry.desandro.com/ JS.